# ¿Cómo imprimir una matriz que se vea centrada en un JTextArea?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, netbeans-8.2, jframe

Quiero imprimir una matriz en un `JTextArea` en Java y quisiera que los datos se vean centrados uno debajo del otro.

```
int[][] matriz1 = new int [3][3];
for (int filas = 0; filas < 3; filas++) {
  cajamatriz1.setText(cajamatriz1.getText() + "\n");
  for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 3; columnas++) {
    matriz1[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    cajamatriz1.setText(cajamatriz1.getText()+matriz1[filas][columnas]+" ");
  }
}
```

En la línea de código:

```
cajamatriz1.setText(cajamatriz1.getText() + matriz1[filas][columnas] + " ");
```

estoy agregando un espacio en blanco " " para que se separen los elementos unos de otros, pero esto hace que a la hora de que se visualicen en el `JTextArea` se vea un poco desordenado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual intenté arreglarlo usando un `\t` en vez de un " " (espacio en blanco) pero se separan mucho los elementos y se me deforma un poco todo el cuadro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudiera usar el tabulador (`\t`) sin que se separaran tanto los elementos estaría perfecto.

Comment: Creo que el principal motivo por el que se te desalinean es que por ejemplo en la fila de `8`, ese número solo tiene 1 carácter, no te funcionaría, verificar si el número es de 1 solo dígito agregarle 2 espacios en vez de uno?

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, eso me podría funcionar.

Comment: Podes usar una biblioteca para armado the tablas con caracteres como por ejemplo https://github.com/vdmeer/asciitable#maven y para este tipo de problemas siempre usar una tipografia de ancho fijo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, puedes usar el `\t` para mantener alineados los numeros a una distancia que se puede definir; Debes tener en cuenta que `JTextArea` dispone de un método que permite redefinir el ancho del tabulado que por defecto es de 8 caracteres, [`setTabSize()`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/11/latestSpec/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setTabSize(int)) recibe un argumento entero que va a representar la cantidad de caracteres de separación.

Simplemente especificando un valor menor, por ejemplo `cajamatriz1.setTabSize(4);` veras que ese espaciamiento no es tan grande.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, esto me ha servido!