# tabulacion que ocupe menos

Tags: java, string

Estoy buscando la manera de seguir poniendo en mis strings el caracter **\t** pero que no me utilice tanto espacio.

Cuando exporto un string a un archivo de texto y abro ese archivo con el blog de notas veo que es equivalente a 8 espacios.

Sin embargo, en mi *JTextArea* aparentan por lo menos 15.

¿Hay alguna manera en la que el *JTextArea* saque un \t más estrecho, o cambiar a 4 los espacios que un **\t** son equivalentes?

¿Quizás si cambio la fuente de letra en el *JTextArea*, los tabuladores no me ocupen tanto espacio? ¿Qué fuente de letra que fuese fácil de leer(no me digáis cosas como la letra del nombre del diario new york times) los tabuladores ocupen menos espacio en un *JTextArea*?

Comment: Puede interesarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351127/cómo-imprimir-una-matriz-que-se-vea-centrada-en-un-jtextarea

Comment: Gracias, me viene que ni pintado, al final ahí mencionan el método setTabSize() de la clase JTextArea que me viene de perlas, justo lo que buscaba: Que el texto tenga tabulaciones que me ocupen menos.

Answer (score 0):

Te diría que pruebes a usar fuentes Monospace. Por lo menos podrás saber cuántos carácteres se añaden en el caso del JTextArea.

Comment: Solucionado con el método setTabSize() de la clase JTextArea... gracias al comentario a mi post.